Roth's theorem for primes in a given arithmetic progression to a large modulus
Let $\mathbb{P}_{a, q}$ denote the set of primes congruent to $a$ modulo $q$. Are there any estimates for the number of $3$-Arithmetic Progressions in the set $\mathbb{P}_{a, q}\cap [1, X]$, where $(a, q) = 1$ and $q$ is large as a function of $X$?
For $q$ at most a constant, such an estimate can be given thanks to Green [1]. One can take a slightly better $q$ thanks to the work of Helfgott and Roton [2]. Both works deal with a much more general setting of an arbitrary dense subset of primes. Can one gain in how large of a modulus $q$ is admissible if one restricts specifically to $\mathbb{P}_{a, q}\cap [1, X]$?
To be more precise, I want to know how large of a modulus $q$ one can take as a function of $X$ such that one has a result of the kind
$$|\{(x, y, z): x, y, z\in \mathbb{P}_{a, q}\cap [1, X]\text{ and }x+z=2y\}|\gg \frac{1}{\phi(q)^3}\frac{X^2}{(\log X)^3}.$$
[1] https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0302311
[2] https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.1842

please supply details, references, clear expressions where available

@kodlu I have made some edits, I hope these help improve the quality.

@MathPanda Do you want $\frac{1}{\phi(q)^2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{\phi(q)^3}$?

Maybe mention that q is a function of X much earlier.

@mathworker21 I think the result holds with $1/\phi(q)^2$ as you pointed out, but I am fine with any lower bound that goes to infinity as $X$ goes to infinity.
